# Kartik gridview, floating header thead and tbody not same, yii2

Tags: javascript, php, gridview, yii2

I want to make table gridview with floating header, but tbody and thead is not same.
image after refresh page, before refresh modal
[image: image before refresh]

[image: image after refresh]

after refresh modal
this modal inside pjax
this id setting my gridview

```php
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'  => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'   => $searchModel,
    'summary'       => "Menampilkan  {begin} - {end} data dari total {totalCount} data. ",
    'emptyText'     => "Tidak ada data yang ditemukan.",
    'formatter'     => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter','nullDisplay' => ''],
    'floatHeader'       => true,
    'responsiveWrap'    => false,
    'perfectScrollbar'  => true,
    'columns'       => [
        [
            'class'             => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
            'header'            =>'Pilih',
            'checkboxOptions'   => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {                                
                $user       = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
                $session    = \Yii::$app->session;
                $data       = $session[$user.'salinanresep_centang_racikan2'];
                $item       = $data!=null ? ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id', 'cek'):null;     
                $ck         = $item[$model['obatid']];
                return ['value' => $model['obatid'],'checked'=>$ck,'id'=>$model['obatid']];
            },
        ],
```

please i need help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, and solved it by simply "faking" or triggering "resize" event after pjax reload event.

```js
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

I know that it's not perfect, but it worked in my case.